# Queue wrapper with list

Tags: c++, list, templates, stl, queue

I am having issues with a question on a homework assignment.  I cannot get my `enqueue()` or `dequeue()` functions to work. visual Studio says the class has no member  with the names.  I have included t instructions and all of my code.

I am not sure whether everything else in the code is correct either.

**INSTRUCTIONS**
Write a template queue class as defined below:
 private data member: a STL list
 public member functions:
-empty
-size
-enqueue
-deque
-front
-back
Then write a driver to test the above queue class.

I do not know if the header is correct but it is what I could come up with.

```
//Header File
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

template<typename queueElement>
class Queue
{
public:
    bool empty() const;
    queueElement size();
    void enqueue(const queueElement & value);
    void dequeue();
    queueElement front();
    queueElement back();
private:
    list <queueElement> aList;
};

template<typename queueElement>
inline bool Queue<queueElement>::empty() const
{
    return aList.empty();
}

template<typename queueElement>
queueElement Queue<queueElement>::size()
{
    return size;
}

template<typename queueElement>
void Queue<queueElement>::enqueue(const queueElement & value)
{
    aList.push_back(value);
}

template<typename queueElement>
void Queue<queueElement>::dequeue()
{
    if (!aList.empty())
    {
        aList.pop_front();
    }
    else
    {
    cout << "Queue is Empty!" << endl;
    }
}

template<typename queueElement>
queueElement Queue<queueElement>::front()
{
    return aList.front();
}

template<typename queueElement>
queueElement Queue<queueElement>::back()
{
    return aList.back();
}
```

This is my driver to test and it is where the errors are showing up.

```
//Driver
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <list>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    list<int> intList;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        intList.enqueue(i); //problem with enqueue
    }
    cout << "Size: " << intList.size() << endl;
    intList.dequeue(); //problem with dequeue
    intList.dequeue(); //problem with dequeue
    cout << "Size after dequeue: " << intList.size() << endl;
    cout << "Front: " << intList.front() << endl;
    cout << "Back: " << intList.back() << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two typos, you probably meant to instantiate `intList` as a `Queue`, since `enqueue`, `dequeue`, etc ... are members of `Queue`.

```
Queue<int> intList;
```

The other is because `size()` should return `aList.size()`.

```
template<typename queueElement>
queueElement Queue<queueElement>::size()
{
    return aList.size();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  These two changes fixed it and it ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having issues with a question on a homework assignment. I cannot get my enqueue or dequeue functions to work.

Please, define "issues" and explain what do you mean with "I cannot get my enqueue or dequeue functions to work", "problem with enqueue" and "problem with dequeue"

Anyway, I hope that the `size()` method you show us

```
template<typename queueElement>
queueElement Queue<queueElement>::size()
{
    return size;
}
```

is a transcription error.

If you return simply `size`, I suppose you're returning the address of the `size()` method itself, converted in `queueElement` type (converted in `int`, in you example).

I suppose `size()` should return `aList.size()`, an unsigned integer (I suppose a `std::size_t`), not a `queueElement`. And, maybe, can be a `const` method.

Something as

```
template<typename queueElement>
std::size_t Queue<queueElement>::size() const
{
    return aList.size();
}
```

Comment: When I say I having issues i simply mean that the enqueue and dequeue functions show an error with the exact wording class"std::list<int, std::allocator<int>>" has no member "enqueue".